# PyDev: exceptions while editing python files

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Python files can't be opened for editing in python source editor. Python editor seems to work properly.

From the eclipse log:

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.editor.ScriptEditor.fActionGroups from class org.eclipse.dltk.python.internal.ui.editor.PythonEditor

at org.eclipse.dltk.python.internal.ui.editor.PythonEditor.createActions(PythonEditor.java:82)

Many thanks for any advice

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with Eclipse or that you don't have permission to view the files.
I'd suggest getting PyCharm if you want to keep going with Python. It's a great IDE and I've had absolutely no problems on either Ubuntu or Windos. :)

Comment: Thank you, i will try it

Comment: My suggestion is that instead of using the DLTK editor for Python editing, you use PyDev (http://www.pydev.org), which is the de-facto Python editor in Eclipse -- there's also a standalone version (http://www.liclipse.com which has Eclipse with PyDev builtin -- although it's commercial).

Comment: Thank you, I have installed PyDev. Unfortunately after that I get this error.

Comment: Apparently the default editor is still the one from DLTK -- try uninstalling it or changing the default file association to use PyDev (or start fresh and install only PyDev) -- another option would be using LiClipse: http://www.liclipse.com, which is Eclipse + PyDev builtin (and some other goodies -- but it's commercial).

Comment: thank you very much